# rolling sum of a column in pandas dataframe at variable intervals

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a list of index numbers that represent index locations for a DF.  list_index = [2,7,12]

I want to sum from a single column in the DF by rolling through each number in list_index and totaling the counts between the index points (and restart count at 0 at each index point).  Here is a mini example.

[image]

The desired output is in OUTPUT column, which increments every time there is another 1 from COL 1 and RESTARTS the count at 0 on the location after the number in the list_index.

I was able to get it to work with a loop but there are millions of rows in the DF and it takes a while for the loop to run.  It seems like I need a lambda function with a sum but I need to input start and end point in index.

Something like lambda x:x.rolling(start_index, end_index).sum()?  Can anyone help me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try of cummulative sum and retrieving only 1 values related information , rolling sum with diffferent intervals is not possible

```
a = df['col'].eq(1).cumsum()
df['output'] = a - a.mask(df['col'].eq(1)).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Out:

```
    col output
0   0   0
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   0   0
4   1   1
5   1   2
6   1   3
7   0   0
8   0   0
9   0   0
10  0   0
11  1   1
12  1   2
13  0   0
14  0   0
15  1   1
```